# macOS keeps trying to open .yml files with Xcode after being told to use Atom

Tags: xcode, file-extensions

I use the Atom text editor, and I want to use that to open .yml files.  I do the usual thing:

- right-click on the file
- Hover over 'Open with' and then choose the 'Other' option, which opens a dialog where I can choose the Atom app.
- Before clicking on 'Atom', I tick the "Always open with" box.

Now, if I double click that file, it will open it with Atom, but that only applies to **that specific file**.  Any other .yml file still tries to open with Xcode.

Normally, when I go through this process for a different file extension, the change applies to **all files with that extension**, but for some reason with .yml it only applies to that specific file.

I can't see anything in Xcode's preferences relating to this.

Is there a config file somewhere, perhaps, that needs editing to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get Info on one example, click the 'Open With:' drop menu, select your new default app. Click 'Change All…' beneath that, OK the 'are you sure' message. Test.

[image]