# Sublime don't open files when I use "Always open with" marker on Mac OS

Tags: macos, text-editor, sublimetext

I have an error when I am trying to open csv files with turn on "Always open with"

Error:
“file.csv” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Bin.

When I don't use marker "Always open with" on Mac OS everything work correctly
[image]

Also I did xattr -cr /Applications/Sublime_Text.app
But it didn't work for me.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444060/macos-keeps-trying-to-open-yml-files-with-xcode-after-being-told-to-use-atom